# Virtualbox crops the screen

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running a VM on virtualbox and it crops the screen. Only the left half of the console is visible, it cuts off somewhere in the middle of the line. Changing the window size doesn't help, as the "image" stays the same and the newly gained window space is just white and empty space. I have tried scaled mode, full screen mode (doesn't work). I changed the maximum guest screen size to be bigger but it doesn't change anything. What do I need to do? The window contents are a Ubuntu server console.

Comment: Did you install Guest Additions into the VM?

Comment: Did you install VBOX Guest Extensions for the Guest machine?

Comment: @music2myear No, do I need to?

Comment: @John No, do I need to?

Comment: I suggest installing Guest Extensions to see if that helps.

Comment: If there are interaction issues between the host and guest, that is always the first step.

Comment: @John I don't think I can, actually. I'm doing this for a university assignment and I'm not allowed to add any files to the server, so I can't download the guest additions iso

Comment: /me scratches head.  Any assignment wit virtual machines requires VMware Tools or VBOX Guest Extensions.

Comment: @John it's a pretty basic one and it's about the stuff we do on the VM, not using VMs in general. I'm not happy about this either :')

Comment: If you cannot at least test, to see if the extensions will solve the problem, then there is nothing else we can suggest.  I don't understand how you are expected to have a working VM with the VirtualBox extensions installed.